# Adding a List to a TableLayoutPanel through a Loop

Tags: c#, list, loops, tablelayoutpanel

I have a file that stores flight information and then I have a search form that allows a user to select a starting city and state, destination city and state, the departure date and number of seats they want to book.

I then have the results of the matched flights getting printed into a TableLayoutPanel. My issue is that when the program loops through to find the flights, it adds them, but if it finds multiple flights, the previous indexes are all replaced with the current one. Here is my code that searches through the flights (the lists are all label lists):

```
    private void searchFlights()
    {
        StreamReader sr = File.OpenText("F:\\C#\\Airline\\Flight.txt");
        string read = null;
        Button button = new Button();
        button.Text = "Book";
        totalSeats = int.Parse(peopleSearchComboBox.Text);
        while ((read = sr.ReadLine()) != null)
        {
            String[] flights = read.Split(' ');
            testSeats = int.Parse(flights[6]);
            if (cityStartSearchTextBox.Text == flights[2] & stateStartComboBox.Text == flights[3] & cityDestinationSearchTextBox.Text == flights[4] &
                stateDestComboBox.Text == flights[5] & dateSearchTextBox.Text == flights[7] & totalSeats <= testSeats)
            {
                airlineSearchLabel.Text = flights[0];
                priceSearchLabel.Text = flights[1];
                seatSearchLabel.Text = flights[6];
                startCityLabel.Text = flights[2];
                startStateLabel.Text = flights[3];
                endCityLabel.Text = flights[4];
                endStateLabel.Text = flights[5];

                price.Add(priceSearchLabel);
                airline.Add(airlineSearchLabel);
                seatsMatch.Add(seatSearchLabel);
                buttons.Add(button);
                cityStartMatch.Add(startCityLabel);
                stateStartMatch.Add(startStateLabel);
                cityDestMatch.Add(endCityLabel);
                stateDestMatch.Add(endStateLabel);
                flightsMatched++;
                Console.WriteLine(airline[0].Text); //I have this to check the index and on each pass through its different
            }
        }
        sr.Close();
    }
```

And here is my code for printing it to the table:

```
private void fillTable()
    {
        blankTableLabel.Text = "";
        priceTableLabel.Text = "Price";
        seatsTableLabel.Text = "Open Seats";
        airlineTableLabel.Text = "Airline";
        noMatchedFlightsLabel.Text = "No Matches Found";
        flightsSearchedTable.RowCount = flightsMatched + 1;
        flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(blankTableLabel,0,0);
        flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(priceTableLabel,1,0);
        flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(airlineTableLabel,2,0);
        flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(seatsTableLabel,3,0);

        if (AppendTexts.totalFlights != 0 & flightsMatched != 0)
        {
            for (int x = 0; x < flightsMatched; x++)
            {
                if (WelcomeScreen.memberLoggedInCheck == true)
                {
                    flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(buttons[x]);
                    flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(price[x]);
                    flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(airline[x]);
                    flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(seatsMatch[x]);
                }
                else
                {
                    flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(price[x],1,x+1);
                    flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(airline[x],2,x+1);
                    flightsSearchedTable.Controls.Add(seatsMatch[x],3,x+1);
                }
            }
        }
```

And this is what an example flight would look like that is stored in the file:
Southwest 80 Austin Texas Miami Florida 180 12/04/2011

Answer (score 0):

Nevermind I was able to figure it out. I just needed to reset the labels each time when going through the loop.

Answer (score 0):

It does not seem like you have your table layout panel setup to allow multiple flights to be added.

I's assuming you are using visual studio. Create a table layout panel using the ui editor and study the code it creates in the design file. Then add another row of data and study the design file again and take note of what was added.

Make sure that your code des everything VS does to make a new row/col.

Then practice populating the rows/columns in VS and make sure your code does the corectly also